# Bootstrap-Datepicker not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

My bootstrap-datetimepicker is not working properly
This question has been asked a lot of times here, but the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046708/bootstrap-datepicker-not-working-correctly), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27336071/does-not-work-datepicker-bootstrap) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058725/bootstrap-datepicker-not-working) and manny others didn't help me further...

at the top of my webpage in the`<head>` i'm including:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and then in my `form` i want to call him like this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="control-label" for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
       <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" value="" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

and at the bottom before the `</body>` tag there is the `javascript/jquery` part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#datetimepicker').datepicker();
</script>
```

What am i doing wrong ? Can someone correct my mistakes ?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: yes when i want to select something from the input field it is not showing the datepicker...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've read that bootstrap datepicker requires jquery 1.7.1 and up

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4es2tew/) im using jquery 1.9.1

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <label class="control-label" for="birthday">Birthday:</label>
       <div class="form-group">
          <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker'>
              <input type='text' class="form-control" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" value="" />
              <span class="input-group-addon">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
              </span>
           </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i also had to include this https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css

Answer (score 1):

Try wrap plugin initialization in [document ready function](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: won't work... is this an issue with working on localhost ?

Comment: Check browser console for bugs. 'ctrl+shift+j' in chrome. Are there any errors?

Also try move 'bootstrap.min.js' before 'bootstrap-datepicker.min.js'. Order of importing js files should be:
1. jquery